# Possible to have hosted services running on there own thread?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I noticed `HostedServices` are ran in a single threaded Async mode. Is it possible to have each hosted service running on its own thread?  I am having several hosted services running, for testing purposes they are just clones of each other -

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<SportsbookEventService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<SportsbookEventService1>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<SportsbookEventService2>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<SportsbookEventService3>();
```

My proof of concept service

```
    public class SportsbookEventService : BackgroundService
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        public SportsbookEventService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, ILogger<SportsbookEventService> logger) : base(scopeFactory, logger)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    timer.Restart();
                    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
                    var tasks = new List<Task>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                    {
                        //This function just makes an async http request
                        tasks.Add(data.ProcessSchedule(SportLeagues.MLB, logger));
                    }
                    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                    timer.Stop();
                    logger.LogWarning(timer.Elapsed.ToString(@"m\:ss\.fff"));

                    await Task.Delay(1, stoppingToken);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But when debugging It seemed they were being processed in a single threaded async manner.  These are short lived constantly running services(They have a 0ms delay between runs and each run will last about 1second).  I need multiple threads because Http requests often get bottle necked when running in single threads asynchronously(I can make 500http requests in 1 second if I am making 50requests per thread, but trying to run 500http requests on a single thread will take 5+seconds)

tldr - I want each service added to be ran on there own long-lived thread.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Asp.net core is running by multiple thread by default, the CPU and core runtime will help to assign the thread at the more effort way. In my opinion, there is no need to do these things by yoursefl.

Comment: @BrandoZhang asp.net core does split up tasks aggressively enough for my use case.  I can have 10 services each on there own thread processing 20 requests much faster than if I have 1 process try to process 200 requests.

Comment: You should understand the thread concept, the asp.net core process will create the thread by default and the thread has the limit, it will be as same as the CPU core count. If you don't have the 20 core CPU, it will not execute the 20 CPU at the same time.